# Vim is not installing on fedora

Tags: linux, vim, fedora

Whenever i am trying to installing vim .. its showing the error

```
[MIRROR] vim-common-8.2.109-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/fedora-mirror/fedora/linux/updates/30/Everything/x86_64/Packages/v/vim-common-8.2.109-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
[MIRROR] vim-filesystem-8.2.109-1.fc30.noarch.rpm: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/fedora-mirror/fedora/linux/updates/30/Everything/x86_64/Packages/v/vim-filesystem-8.2.109-1.fc30.noarch.rpm [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
[MIRROR] vim-enhanced-8.2.109-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/fedora-mirror/fedora/linux/updates/30/Everything/x86_64/Packages/v/vim-enhanced-8.2.109-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
[MIRROR] vim-filesystem-8.2.109-1.fc30.noarch.rpm: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/fedora/updates/30/Everything/x86_64/Packages/v/vim-filesystem-8.2.109-1.fc30.noarch.rpm [Could not resolve host: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems like there is an error with your internet connection or your DNS.

Try to ping google:

```
ping google.com -c 3
```

and check if it resolves to an IP address or if you get any response at all.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes ।। When I shift in another room its installed .